# drupal 7 page defined by hook_menu not found

Tags: javascript, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have tried everything I have found on the internet to no avail.

The module provides external authentication handled by an iframe.  When the authentication completes, a message is sent to the socket on the drupal page with success or failed status.
In the event of success, the module needs to communicate again with the external server to get the userid on drupal to complete the login.

Two things:
(1) The drupal must have no knowledge of the external credentials, and
(2) the username/password on the external authenticator are independent of the drupal username/password.

The name of the module is 'yauisauth'.

Given that, I have the following in hook_menu:

```
function yauisauth_menu() {
  $items['yauisauth/callback/%'] = array(
  'title' => 'yauis login completion',
  'description' => 'coordinates yauis login with drupal login',
  'access callback' => user_is_anonymous,
  'file' => 'yauisauth.inc',
  'page callback' => 'yauisauth_callback',
  'page arguments' => array(2),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
$items['yauisauth/failed'] = array(
  'title' => 'login failed',
  'description' => 'login failed',
  'access callback' => user_is_anonymous,
  'file' => 'yauisauth.inc',
  'page callback' => 'yauis_login_failed',
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
return $items;
```

}

The callback is invoked from the javascript:

```
return_to = 'yauisauth/callback/';   
return_to += transid;
jQuery.post(return_to, null, null);
```

The error I get is:

```
POST http://localhost/drupal7/yauisauth/callback/4ddcd4ab-5167-4aa5-bafa-ee46812237d8 404 (Not Found)
```

Obvious, I am not constructing the url in a way that drupal wants to see it but I don't know what to do.

Originally, I had all the functions in yauisauth.module but then split the callback functions and the ones it calls into yauisauth.inc

Between each change, I do the following:

(in mysql):

UPDATE system SET status='0' WHERE name='yauisauth';
  DELETE FROM cache_bootstrap WHERE cid='system_list';

then in bash:

```
drush -cc menu
drush -cc all
```

(Blindly following every instruction I can find on the net.)

The callback function looks like:

```
function yauisauth_callback($transid) {
  $attr = get_attributes($transid);
  if (empty($attr)) { 
      return drupal_not_found();
  } 
  ... // calls to other functions local to the yauisauth.inc file
}
```

Can anyone tell me why my invocation of the callback function is failing and what I can do to make it work?

Based on advice received elsewhere, I changed my drupal to reside at the document root of a virtual host and put the entire url into the javascript call - window.location.origin + '/yauisauth/callback'.  An alert informs me that the url is constructed correctly.

I have a "die" at the beginning of the callback function that never gets executed.

If I put the url in the address bar, the "die" statement is executed so the route is found.

Still looking for advice.

Comment: Why do you do those MySQL commands? You only need to clear the (menu) cache for the `hook_menu` entries to be discovered. Are you positive you're not the one returning the `drupal_not_found` page in your callback? (that is, that `$attr` is not empty?)

Comment: The mysql commands are to unregister the module after changes. I am not returning a drupal_not_found page, I am getting the not found message in the console.

Comment: You do not need to re-register the module. Simply clear the menu cache from Drush (`drush cc menu`) or by visiting `admin/config/development/performance`. You are returning a `drupal_not_found` if `$attr` is empty in the code that you pasted. Are you positive that's not what is getting hit?

Comment: I just put a "die" immediately after the call to get_attributes and it is not executed - I still get the 'not found' message in my javascript console.  How do I construct the url for the post so that is is found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just took another look at your code – you're adding underscores when none are needed, for example `page_callback` should be `page callback`. See: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.

Comment: Thanks, Charlie - I fixed that, still don't correctly get my new page.

Comment: If you can post the revised code and verify that hitting the URL manually in your browser doesn't fix it I can try to help.

Comment: I made recommended changes above.  When I try the url localhost/drupal7/yauisauth/callback I get "The requested URL /usr/share/drupal7/index.php was not found on this server." Note that it is not refusing my route but instead refusing index.php using the filesystem address for drupal 7 instead of the web address (/usr/share/drupal7 instead of localhost/drupal7).  Apparently I need to do something different for the routing but I don't know what.

Comment: This actually did solve that problem but the fact that it was ok was masked by a different problem.  Thank you.